# How do I get an F# fsx script to re-execute and re-pull SQL data each time it's called from C#?

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data, f#-scripting, fsharp.data.typeproviders

I have written a simple C# web app that allows the user to input some data and then upon button click:

1. the data is saved to a local SQL db
2. an F# script is called to retrieve that data using SqlCommandProvider
3. that data is passed back to C#
4. the passed back data is used in some calculations
5. the calc results are displayed onto the screen of the web page

Everything works fine except that when the button is clicked more than once, the same data is sent back from F# from the very first execution.

It appears that the script is not re-executing as would be expected, but if it is, it seems that the SqlCommandProvider might be locked to the first set of results that it initially returned.

It is obviously unnecessary to send the data to the db and back in order to perform these calcs. This app is being built for demonstration purposes of F#/C# usage together in a solution, not actual efficient production usage of the app.

```
#I "../packages/FSharp.Data.3.0.0/lib/net45"
#r "FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data

#I "../packages/FSharp.Data.SqlClient.2.0.1/lib/net40"
#r "FSharp.Data.SqlClient.dll"
open FSharp.Data.SqlClient

[<Literal>]
let ConnectionString = 
    @"server=(local); database=CostPriceCalc; user id=MyId; password=MyPassword;"

[<Literal>]
let SqlQuery = "SELECT SharesSold, PricePerShare, SellDate, CostMethod FROM [CalcInputs] WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM [CalcInputs])"
let cmd = new SqlCommandProvider<SqlQuery, ConnectionString>(ConnectionString)
let result = cmd.Execute() |> Seq.toArray
```

Additionally, I am not yet handling the data properly coming back from F#, instead I'm very inelegantly just converting to string and parsing through it to get what I need. That however, seems irrelevant (other than it's massively incorrect) because the C# variables are clear each time before pulling from F# and the same data just keeps coming back each time from F#.

```
   public static List<NewData.Values> ParseFsharpData()
    {
        var parsedList = new List<NewData.Values>();
        foreach (var item in CalculateCostPrice.result)
        {
            var parsedData = item.ToString().Replace(";", ",").
                Replace("{ ", "").Replace(" }", "").Replace("Some ", "").
                Replace("M,", ",").Replace("\"", "").
                Split(',').ToList();
            parsedList = (from value in parsedData
                select new NewData.Values
                {
                    Value1 = value.Split('=')[0].Trim(),
                    Value2 = value.Split('=')[1].Trim()
                }).ToList();
        }
        return parsedList;
    }
```

Lastly, I have confirmed that the new data IS being written correctly to the db. The issue seems confined to either the F# fsx script itself (named CalculateCostPrice) not re-executing as expected, OR the SqlCommandProvider caching the data.

Comment: How are you invoking the F# script from C# and how are you receiving the data back? Can you include the C# code that does this? Also, if you were to compile the F# code as a dll, communication would be much easier and faster.

Comment: To check if the CommandProvider caches the query you could add an additional field in the Select that just gets the current date/second like `"SELECT ...,  " + DateTime.Now.Second + " as CurrentSecond FROM ...`. That would circumvent the cache for testing purposes.

Comment: @AMieres The place I reference the F# piece is where `CalculateCostPrice.result` is shown in the C# code posted. I am not doing anything else in C# to hit the fsx script.

Comment: @AMieres Sorry, and I did forget to mention that I am compiling the FSX script as a dll and the C# project references that dll in its location on disc. I actually never figured out how to do it any other way.

Comment: @Markus Deibel Thank you for the timestamp idea! Just for testing, I replaced the query I was using with `SELECT GETDATE()` which I then called several times in a row in debug mode, waiting several second in between each call. The time that was returned was the exact same value with each call regardless of how long I waited before executing the next call. It does seem that the query results are being cached somehow on the F# side or the FSX script's results are being cached somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried to compile .fsx scripts yet, but my experience with using modules in F# projects makes me think that:

```
let result = cmd.Execute() |> Seq.toArray
```

compiles to a static variable on the CalculateCostPrice class. This would mean it'll only get executed once (when it's first used, if not earlier), and the result would be stored in the "result" variable.

Adding a parameter of type "unit" should change it to a method (again, not tested yet):

```
let result() = cmd.Execute() |> Seq.toArray
```

And you would call it from C# as:

```
foreach (var item in CalculateCostPrice.result())
```

In this case, the execution will happen when you call the method, not when the class gets initialized. I might rename it from "result" to "executeQuery" or something along those lines.

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer. `result` needs to be a function so it gets executed everytime.

Comment: @libertyernie This solved the problem immediately. Thank you for the precise answer leaving no room for guessing as I'm horrible at F#, was running out of time, and this'd had me stopped dead in my tracks. Thanks to everyone here for helping me out with this!